# Jhipster project in company's App server - jndi datasource

Tags: jhipster

I am quite new to Jhipster. I would appreciate some one can tell me, how can I access jndi Datasource, defined in Application server. Where in spring boot, i need to put it. 
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you read the spring boot docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource. Also be warned that deploying in an app server is more complex than running as an executable jar, JHipster team clearly recommends the executable jar.

Comment: I understand, but have to use container's DS.. application must run in application server

Comment: It's just that unless you already did it, you should start first by deploying your jhipster app into your app server without worrying about the DS (try with default dev war embedding h2 db). Much work here and maybe you'll change your mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your Spring Boot application to an Application Server, you might want to configure and manage your DataSource by using your Application Server’s built-in features and access it by using JNDI.

The spring.datasource.jndi-name property can be used as an alternative to the spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.username, and spring.datasource.password properties to access the DataSource from a specific JNDI location. For example, the following section in application.properties shows how you can access a JBoss AS defined DataSource:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/customers
```

in your case need to change the application.yml

```
spring:     
    datasource:
         jndi-name: "java:/your/datasource"
```

and remove url.

FOR MORE INFO 
[spring boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource)